# Wrong inheritance behavior in factory boy factories

Tags: python, django, factory-boy

I have several factories with structure like this:

```
AbstractFactoryMinimal(DjangoModelFactory):
    comment = ''

AbstractFactoryFull(AbstractFactoryMinimal):
    comment = Faker(provider='text', max_nb_chars=2000)

FactoryMinimal(AbstractFactoryMinimal):
    field = ''

    class Meta(object):
        model = SomeModel

FactoryFull(FactoryMinimal, AbstractFactoryFull):
    field = Faker(provider='text', max_nb_chars=2000)

obj = FactoryFull()
print(obj.comment) # expect some text from faker, but got '' instead
print(obj.field)   # works like expected, return some random text
```

In models I have

```
AbstractModel(TimeStampedModel)
```

and

```
SomeModel(AbstractModel)
```

I even look at mro and it's looks like exactly how I expected it to look:

```
(FactoryFull,
FactoryMinimal,
AbstractFactoryFull,
AbstractFactoryMinimal,
factory.django.DjangoModelFactory,
factory.base.Factory,
factory.base.BaseFactory,
object)
```

So "comment" field should be generated by faker and not just set with ''. Why it is work this way? How I can implement factories to see expected behavior?

EDIT:
I can change inheritance order in last factory to this:

```
FactoryFull(AbstractFactoryFull, FactoryMinimal)
```

it will work but then, if I want to override field in FactoryMinimal it wouldn't work. And sometimes I need exactly this feature. And anyway, this isn't normal inheritance behavior in Python in first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found some workaround.

Basically, I change inheritance order and repeat some code. Like this:

```
FactoryMinimal(AbstractFactoryMinimal):
    field = ''

    class Meta(object):
        model = SomeModel

FactoryFull(AbstractFactoryFull, FactoryMinimal):
    field = Faker(provider='text', max_nb_chars=2000)

    class Meta(object):
        model = SomeModel
```

And if I need to override something from base class I use MixIn class for this:

```
CommentFieldMixIn(DjangoModelFactory):
    comment = 'Something Completely Different'

FactoryMinimal(AbstractFactoryMinimal):
    field = ''

    class Meta(object):
        model = SomeModel

FactoryFull(CommentFieldMixIn, AbstractFactoryFull, FactoryMinimal):
    field = Faker(provider='text', max_nb_chars=2000)

    class Meta(object):
        model = SomeModel
```

Only one problem remain: how I can say anyone who would maintain my code why I do this in every factory.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Scan the inheritance chain, starting from the furthest point,
# excluding the current class, to retrieve all declarations.
for parent in reversed(self.factory.__mro__[1:]):
    ...
```

The reason you can see above. Also check test in this commit https://github.com/FactoryBoy/factory_boy/commit/e2ef7c96ed74b35b9dec75a7f222b6ffa9214c10 
I'm in doubts why it so. Maybe ask an author of this library about motivation?

Comment: It's cool to know, but how I can achieve behavior I want then?

Comment: Since you can't rely on MRO without modifying the library - avoid using multi inheritance in that way (and mb at all except mixins). That's my only suggestion.